# I want use diazo to replace a attribute, but diazo's <replace /> statement with attributes is not work?

Tags: plone, diazo

I have some code as below, but attribute 'src' not replace,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules
    xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo"
    xmlns:css="http://namespaces.plone.org/diazo/css"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <rules css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper">

        <theme href="index.html" />
        <replace css:content="a#portal-logo img" css:theme="h1.logo a img" attributes="src"/>

    </rules>

</rules>
```

Why? is a bug? or I make a mistake? Have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

if you set, in your theme, src="" you can use also

```
<merge attributes="class" css:theme="h1.logo a img" css:content="a#portal-logo img" />
```

or

```
<replace css:content-children="a#portal-logo img" attribute="src">
        <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="./@src"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
</replace>
```

Comment: by first rule, do you mean attributes="src" instead of "class"?
`<merge attributes="src" css:theme="h1.logo a img" css:content="a#portal-logo img" />`

I try the above `merge` rule, and it does update `src` to:
`<img sr="/++theme++my.theme/%20http://example.com/logo.png" ...>`

For the `<replace />` rule, nothing seems changed.

One of the real issue from @Andy's question is that do we need `<xsl:attribute ... />` within `<replace attributes="src" ...>` for http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/basic.html to work? If so, that is not explicitly described in the document, which causes confusing.

Comment: You're right. In the first option there is an error: attributes="src".
In the second option try to substitute <xsl:value-of select="./src"/> with <xsl:value-of select="//h1[@class='logo']/img/a/@src" />.

Comment: On gistboxapp.com search for a group called "diazo", there are useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [copy](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/basic.html#copy) instead of replace. As Diazo docs say in replace section...

> Note: As with  rules working on tags, if the named
>   attribute(s) do not exist on the both the theme and content nodes,
>   nothing will happen. If you want to copy attributes regardless of
>   whether they exist on the theme node(s) or not, you can use 
>   instead.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a right way.
Beacuse in my case, "a#portal-logo img" and "h1.logo a img" exist at the sametime.
Why not work ?

Comment: what happens if you leave out  attributes="src"?

Comment: If I leave out attributes="src",  will work exactly, replace the <img /> tag complete, so I'm sure the <replace /> statement is correct.

Comment: Hmm, what you trying to do here anyway? It looks like you are trying to replace the theme's logo with the Plone logo... why would you want to do that?  I've replaced the href on the link before, but not the img src...